# Air bubble's weight measurement

Tags: gas, weight, liquid-state, amorphous-solids

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_(physics)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap_bubble

https://www.instagram.com/p/CE4FSctpCdu/?utm_source=ig_web_button_share_sheet

Is it possible to create air bubbles other than soap water as origin?

Can we classify air bubble as solid, liquid or gas?

Can we measure air bubble's weight by performing experiments?

Comment: Did you ever see water boiling?

Comment: Yes. Can we measure Air bubble's weight by performing experiments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weigh a container holding some egg whites. Whisk the egg whites vigorously for a while, and weigh again.

Given that the density of air (at STP, so probably not exactly where you will be) is 1.29 grams / liter it might require rather a lot of egg whites with a lot of whisking to see any difference (depending on the accuracy of your scales).

Comment: Why would the air that's incorporated into the egg weigh more than it did when it was sitting on top of the egg?  (This demonstraion works with a balloon, but that's because the contained air is under pressure, and therefore denser than it was before.)

Comment: Very good question and I expect that you'd need a really sensitive set of scales to detect anything. However, I think the density of the air in the bubbles in the egg should be higher than 'free' air, because they're being compressed by the weight of the egg above them as well as the air above the egg. Very small effect, I'd expect, but there..